# How to enable logging in chef at each step in the cookbook

Tags: logging, chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

I have a cookbook that performs some installation on the target node. I want to log the output of chef client run in /var/log/. I want to embed certain code in the recipe that logs the output.

```
java "java home" do
    java_source "https://url
    action :install
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From inside a recipe, you can do this:

```
log 'message' do   
  message 'A message add to the log.'   
  level :info 
end
```

or, using code:

`Chef::Log.debug "Your message here"`

https://docs.chef.io/resource_log.html

Answer (score 0):

You can control the Chef log level via either the `log_level` option in `client.rb` or the `--log-level` (`-l`) command ling flag. You can log additional data using the `log` resource from your recipe code.

Comment: the requirement is to write a code in the recipe itself.I have updated the question with sample cod.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but you can change the log level from inside Chef using `Chef::Log.level = :debug`. If you want to set it around a specific resource, use two `ruby_block` resources. One before `java` to set it to debug and one after to set it back to the original log level.

Comment: like i want to use the log resource how can i do that